# Apparent limit on the script output

Tags: php, html, output

So I've got this really simple script:

```
<?php

for($n = 0; $n < 50000; $n++) {
    echo "a";
}
```

- If I run it on local server (xampp), the output I get is, as expected, 50.000 "a"s.
- But! When I run it on the web server it outputs only the first 24525 characters. Sometimes a bit more, but not much more. 90% of the time output is limited to that.

Target machine is a VPS which I have no control over. Cloudflare is also running in case that is relevant. I've got no idea what's causing this.

Is there any PHP setting that limits the output size? Or Cloudflare's? I didn't find anything at all about this anywhere online.

It's not a browser issue by the way, it happens at all browsers. Works every time at localhost, and fails at remote.

***Edit***: Max execution time, 15 seconds in the PHP config, is not reached, not by far.
Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: could be max execution time setting, a php ini setting which you probably don't have any control over

Comment: @TerryKernan But `echo "a"`, even 50k times, takes less than 5 seconds to run. I will try with ini_set to put a higher one but it'd be weird to have max exec to less than 10s... I think.

Comment: Updated question with max exect time. Its 15s so it can't be that.

Comment: If you look at your webpage with a non-browser useragent, such as http://web-sniffer.net, what does it say the content length is? Also, the a's are all on one line, right? Stupid question, but what happens if you output some returns at regular intervals?

Comment: @MrLister Doesn't change much. Sometimes it increases the lines in the output though.